# [nextjs]: getStaticProps missing params key during development

Tags: javascript, next.js

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
   return {
      paths: [
         { params: { slug: 'article-1' } },
         { params: { slug: 'article-2' } },
      ],
      fallback: false,
   }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
   // params is undefined
   return {
      props: { slug: '' },
   }
}
```

`getStaticProps` gets this object,

```
{ locales: undefined, locale: undefined, defaultLocale: undefined }
```

and is missing params key. `getStaticPaths` must be passing the params but for some reason `getStaticProps` doesnt have it.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the mistake, this two functions were supposed to be called in a dynamic route for ex. `[slug].js` in my case. I called them in the file `pages/blog/index.js` where this no params being passed since it's not a dynamic route.

Moving the functions to page `pages/blog/[slug].js` made it work.